# Probability of two element's intersection

Tags: probability

Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be disjoint events where 
\begin{align*}
P(A) & = 0.50\\
P(B) & = 0.30\\
P(C) & = 0.20
\end{align*}
If $D = B \cup C$, what is the value of $P(C \mid D)$?

I know that

$$P(C \mid D) = \frac{P(C \cap D)}{P(D)}$$

But how do I get  $P(C \cap D)$ with only this info given?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Ok. I will. thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that since $C \subset D$  we have $C \cap D=C$.

Comment: so it'd be P(C)/P(D)?

Comment: Exactly, this is all.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
P(C|D) &= \frac{P(C \cap D )}{P(D)}\\
&=\frac{P(C \cap (B\cup C))}{P(D)}\\
&= \frac{P(CB\cup C)}{P(D)}\\
&=\frac{P(CB\cup C)}{P(D)}\\
&=\frac{P(CB)+P(C)-P(BC)}{P(D)}\\
&=\frac{P(\varnothing)+P(C)-P(\varnothing)}{P(D)}\\
&=\frac{P(C)}{P(D)}
\end{align*}
This is a long winded way of saying the other answer: $C\subset D \implies C\cap D = C$.